# Select all Text in Entry when Focused

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I wanted to select the entire Text when an Entry is focused so that the Input can be made quicker without having to delete the initial input.

Therefore, I added the following code:

**XAML**

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Min, Mode=TwoWay}" Focused="Entry_Focused" />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;

    entry.CursorPosition = 0;
    entry.SelectionLength = entry.Text == null ? 0 : entry.Text.Length;
}
```

In my **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)** Emulator it behaves like that when I click my Entry with the mouse.

[image]

When I move ahead with **Tab** (which the user does not have) it behaves correctly as you can see here

[image]

What is the correct way to solve this issue so that it behaves like on the second screenshot when a user clicks into the Entry and sets the focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to cursor do not work correctly, when inside Android’s Focused event. This is true regardless of language (happens for native Java apps also).

The fix is to **queue** the changes, so they happen after the method returns. This can be done with Dispatch:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch( () =>
{
    // your code here
});
```

In your case, put all the code of Entry_Focused inside the Dispatch.

Comment: Thanks, I put the Dispatcher-Code in my Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)-Method and put my code to select the entire text there. It worked as expected. I marked it as anser. Thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: I was about to give up, then I stumbled on this, this answer works!

Comment: Hey Steve, It seems when you focus on something else and refocus the entry even with the dispatcher the selection does not work, do you think this could be a MAUI issue? Or Am i missing something!